# My muscles becoming stiff while workout

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, workout, exercise-technique, post-workout

I started workouts 3 months ago.My muscles are becoming stiff while workout. My trainer suggest me full body massage. Is this the right way to go full body massage or what is the reason behind the stiffness and how to get rid of this stiffness. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

- **Not enough sleep:** You need at least 8 hours good sleep a day.
- **Not enough food:** Your body needs good, nutritional food to recover effectively.
- **Not enough warmup:** Before doing exercise, perform some light movements and appropriate stretching. For example, before I do my back workout I start with rowing 1000m and 5 mins of stretching.

Comment: I sleep at least 8 hrs a day and taking whey protein after workout. Even i do warm up at least  10 min. may be cause of nutritional food.